# How to modify csv data in amcharts export

Tags: amcharts

I want to modify csv data while export from amcharts.
Scenario is like : I have 2 column 1 with values and other with 0. Now i dont want that column to display in the csv which have 0 values.

I did not find anything for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `processData` for that. See more here: https://github.com/amcharts/export#changing-the-dataprovider-when-exporting

```
  "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "processData": function (data, cfg) {

              if (cfg.format === 'CSV') {
                    return data.map(function (item) {
                          // Ignore the second column
                          return {
                                firstColumn: item.firstColumn
                          };
                    });
              }

              return data;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `processData` way is fine for datas that do not much differ to the `dataProvider`.

Amcharts's doc is not very well documented about this, but after a bit of digging, I found this way :

```javascript
var myChart = AmCharts.makeChart('chart-id', {
    dataProvider: myDatas, // Some datas
    export: {
        enabled: true,
        // Using the 'menu' option in order to override its behavior ...
        menu: [{
            class: 'export-main',
            menu: [{
                label: 'Download as ...',
                menu: ['PNG', 'JPG', 'SVG', 'PDF']
            }, {
                label: 'Save as ...',
                menu: [{
                    label: 'CSV',
                    // Overriding CSV export behavior :
                    click: function exportCSV() {
                        // This will export the 'myDatas' datas to a string formatted as a CSV.
                        // Feel free to change the 'data' option of the 'toCSV()' method for a different CSV.
                        myChart.export.toCSV({ data: myDatas }, function(data) {
                            // 'data' is a string containing the CSV
                            // This will download the CSV to the file MyCSV.csv !
                            this.download(data, this.defaults.formats.CSV.mimeType, 'MyCSV.csv');
                        });
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                label: 'Annotate ...',
                action: 'draw',
                menu: [{
                    class: 'export-drawing',
                    menu: ['PNG', 'JPG']
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

This will export and download a CSV file with the desired datas !